# secp256k1 point density

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am working on a crypto project using the secp256k1 elliptic curve.

I know that I can select a random point $P = (x, y)$ from the curve by randomly selecting the first coordinate $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ (where $p$ is the prime of the elliptic curve field $\mathbb{F}_p$) and computing the second coordinate $y$ using the curve equation $y^2 = x^3 + 7$. Because the cofactor of the curve is $h = 1$, for every value $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ that spawns a valid $y \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, there is a point on the curve with coordinates $x, y$. In case there is a value $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ for which the curve equation does not find a valid value for $y \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, that means there is simply no point on the curve at that $x$ coordinate.

I also know that the curve order is $q$, with $q < p$. That means there exist $q$ valid points on the curve, which is less than all the values that $x$ could have in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

My question is: How far are points from each other, in respect to the $x$ coordinate? What is the largest distance between two points on the curve? Is there any documentation in this regard?

Comment: In which coordinate system? You do understand that the discrete modular curves do not look like curves in the X,Y coordinate system, right? And that although $q < p$, the value of $q$ is only a tiny bit smaller than $p$ for the curves we use for cryptographic operations...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "distance"?

Comment: By distance between two points (in respect to the $x$ coordinate) I mean the following: 
Having two valid points $P_1 = (x_1, y_1)$ and $P_2 = (x_2, y_2)$, with all $x \in (x_1, x_2)$ generating invalid points, the distance between $P_1$ and $P_2$ is $|x_1 - x_2|$.

Answer (score 3):

> I  also know that the curve order is $q$, with $q<p$. That means there exist $q$ valid points on the curve,

True

> which is less than all the values that $x$ could have in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Actually, that's less relevant than you think.

- For every $x$ value in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ that has a valid solution, there are two values of $y$ that satisfy the equation (and hence correspond to two points).  It's easy to see, if $(x, y)$ is a solution, then so is $(x, -y)$ (aka $(x, p-y)$)

Note: some elliptic curve have 1 or 3 $x$ values that correspond to a single $y$ value (which is the $y$ value 0) - secp256k1 is not one of those curves.

In addition, there is a single 'point of infinity' which doesn't correspond to a solution to the equation, but is thrown in as an additional group element.

Hence, there are exactly $(q-1)/2$ $x$ values that correspond to (at least one) valid point.  Since $p \approx. q$, this if you pick an $x$ value at random, you have almost exactly a 50% probability of picking one with a solution.

Comment: After some more research, I found out the following:

Comment: The largest "distance" between two point is not that relevant, because there could potentially be points at any distance on the curve.
A more interesting question is how easy can you find two points that are $n$ far away from each other. Formally, given a valid point $P = (x, y)$, the probability of the next $n$ consecutive values for the $x$ coordinate to generate invalid points is $2^{-n}$.

Comment: @Hulub: do we know that?  Is there a proof that the valid $x$ coordinates are not non-uniformly distributed?  There might be; I haven't seen such a proof...

Comment: By your argument, that every $x$ value has a probability of $1/2$ to generate a valid point, that also means it has a probability of $1/2$ to generate an INVALID point.
If we take 3 consecutive $x$ values, the probability of all 3 to NOT generate valid points is $1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 = 2^{-3}$. Hence, the generalisation holds.

Comment: @Hulub: that does not follow.  Yes, if we take 3 random $x$ values, the probability is approximately $2^{-3}$ (approximately because the probability of a single value isn't precisely $2^{-1}$).  On the other hand, we don't know if the valid $x$ values are clustered; any correlation because whether successive values are valid would invalidate your argument (and as I said previously, I don't know of any proof about correlation of successive $x$ values)